# Switching between H.264 video streams on the fly?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, linux, mixer, h.264

I have several H.264 encoded MP4 files, as well as still images. From these I want to generate a single video stream that I can broadcast. The stream will be composed of alternating still images and video clips.

Here is what I think could work:

- At any time, simultaneously play back two video streams using `ffmpeg -re` (one of
   the video streams is actually a looping still image).
- Use a H.264 video mixer to switch from one stream to another. The mixer is 
   controlled by a Unix command line script. A playlist wouldn't work since the
   order of streams is not known in advance.
- Pipe the resulting (mixed) H.264 stream into broadcasting software such as Wowza.

*Is that the correct approach? Is there actually a H.264 video mixer that runs on Linux and that can be controlled from the command line?*

Comment: The question is definitely on-topic here but you might get more answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @ProfessorSparkles Thanks for the suggestion. I am also discussing the issue on one of the GStreamer mailing lists. Furthermore, I discovered [FreeJ](http://freej.org/), which seems to be able to do what I want with Ogg Theora, i.e. re-encoding would be required.

Comment: there are som GStreamer based vision mixers: see [here](https://github.com/voc/voctomix) or [here](https://github.com/timvideos/gst-switch)

Comment: Just created a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005612) on StackOverflow, asking if it can be done with GStreamer.